# C Runtime Library issue MD/MDd

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, runtime-error

We have a C library that we want to distribute, alongside C example code.

The library is of course built in release mode.
The example code project is in cmake so that it can be easily run on both Linux and Windows.
On Linux (debug and release) as well as on Windows (release), we have no issue.
However, on Windows (debug), we have an issue when leaving the main : the program triggers an assertion:

```
Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap
Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)
```

Then when continuing the process, it raises the following exception:

```
Unhandled exception at [...] (ntdll.dll)
0xC000000D STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
```

As this seemed related to runtime library, we tryed changing it from MDd (multithreaded dll debug) to MD (multithreaded dll) [ *[more on these here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=vs-2019)* ] and it solved the issue.
However, this seems like a work around rather than a fix: the release library (built with MD) should be usable in a debug program using MDd, right?

As we understand it, conflicts in runtime library only appears when allocation is made in the caller and deallocation is made in the callee or vice-versa.
So we tracked all allocations to check them and everything seems ok.
We ran leak detections on the example code in both Linux (Valgrind) and Windows (CrtDbg) but they didn't find any leak, everything seems fine.

Is it right to expect a release library built with MD to run in an MDd program?
If not, it seems strange: libraries are always distributed in release, yet used in debug solutions while developing...
If yes, what can cause the issue?

Comment: What is MD and MDd?

Comment: Anyway, it sounds more like a heap corruption than a leak. It implies someone is overwriting the heap (passed its allocated memory).

Comment: MD is "multithreaded dll" runtime library and MDd is "multithreaded dll debug" (I have edited the question so that it's clearer)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - I think `MD` & `MDd` are defined _[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=vs-2019)_, but that is not clear in the question.

Comment: It might be a heap corruption but then it should fail in release and/or in linux, right? Also, changing from MDd to MD should not fix it.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie *Anyway, it sounds more like a heap corruption than a leak.*  Indeed.  Microsoft's debug libraries do things like overwrite memory on `free()`, and fill it with non-zero values on allocation.  Running into problems with the debug library but not with the non-debug runtime is a sign of a program that corrupts memory.

Comment: You might also want to try `-fsanitize=undefined` to find undefined behaviour with Linux GCC. Or finally it can be something as devious as an `long int` index used to address an array of > 4G and it would work in Linux because of what `long int` is and in release mode in Windows because overflow ignored...

Comment: Thank you all for your reactivity and your comments! If the cause is heap corruption, shouldn't it present the same issue on Linux debug/release and on Windows release? Also, am I right to expect an MD-generated library to work in an MDd project? (I think so but I could be wrong)

Comment: When the heap is corrupt, it will show Undefined Behavior. That UB will be different on different platforms/compilers. So no, it will not present itself the same.

Comment: As mentioned by Andrew, MS has extra handling of allocated memory for debug version. Writing patterns to allocated memory or adding guard blocks at the end of the allocated area etc. is used to detect more errors. If these mechanisms are not present with release version or Linux version, there is no reason why they should behave same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds more like a heap corruption than a leak. It implies someone is overwriting the heap (passed its allocated memory). Finding it can be pain in the but.

First, check your example code. Strip it down to the bare minimum "hello world" and then build it up until it happens again. Then check the example code. If it is not the example code, check which library functions were called and code-review those.

As an aid, you can use the MS heap check functions. place them at function entry and function exit, or maintain global versions that you regularly check. The following is an example:

```
#include <crtdbg.h>

void example(void)
{
    _CrtMemState memStateStart, memStateEnd, memStateDelta;

    // Make a checkpoint of the heap's state so we can later check the heap is still OK
    _CrtMemCheckpoint( &memStateStart );
    //
    // do your things
    //
    // Check the heap
    _CrtMemCheckpoint( &memStateEnd );
    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_WARN,   _CRTDBG_MODE_WNDW );
    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR,  _CRTDBG_MODE_WNDW );
    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_WNDW );
    if (_CrtMemDifference( &memStateDelta, &memStateStart, &memStateEnd ))
        _CrtMemDumpStatistics( &memStateDelta );
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

Comment: A char* was allocated in the library in a static function but never deallocated. Thus, it was allocated by the callee and disallocated by default by the caller at exit, provoking the runtime library conflict Commenting code and proceeding by dichotomy allowed us to find it and, after fix, the issue disappeared. Thanks a lot everyone!